# Error: You can't change/remove the property type/tag for the xxxxx tag specified in targetConfig lightning__RecordPage. The component is in use

Tags: lightning-web-components

I created a property tag (for our purposes we will call it "isFlow") in the LWC js-meta.xml file, and I decided I wanted to change the data type of the property from String to Boolean. After doing this, and trying to deploy, I was confronted with about 13 separate similar errors as shown below.

> lwc/xxx.js-meta.xml: You can't change the property type for the
> 'isFlow' tag specified in targetConfig lightning__RecordPage. The
> component is in use on a Lightning page.

This question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304820/unable-to-delete-configuration-properties-from-lwc) is similar, but doesn't have a final answer.

My question is since we re-use this component in several places, is there any other way to change/remove this property without having to remove references and save from 13 other places? Then go back add them again? I don't recall design variables in Aura Components being as fussy.

Note: I removed about 6 other properties for security purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="ChsServicesAPI">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage,lightning__AppPage,lightning__HomePage,lightningCommunity__Default,lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="isFlow" type="String"/> <-- Trying to Change this to Boolean -->
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull your Lightning Pages and other dependent metadata down to your local VS Code, run a Find/Replace across your project, and simply do a `force:source:push` or `force:source:deploy`, that will deploy all the changes at once.